# Revoke Expo Push Notification Token

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using Expo for my android application.
My database is compromised, which contains all Expo push notification tokens..
How can i disable those Tokens ??
I searched for this , but i cannot found a solution.Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You can create AccessToken in Organization settings (*/settings/access-tokens*) and enable "Enhanced Security for Push Notifications" which will require access tokens before delivering notifications.

See more here: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#additional-security